# Top layout guide is deprecated in iOS 11

Tags: swift, autolayout, ios11

Since `topLayoutGuide` property is now deprecated in iOS 11, what is alternative to use top layout guide?

```
backView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**TopLayoutGuide** is deprecated in iOS 11 so we have option to use **SafeAreaLayoutGuide** like this :

- First we can get view safeAreaLayoutGuide

> ```
>  let guide = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
> ```

- Second add constraint to guide

  ```
  searchBackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.topAnchor).isActive = true
  ```

Comment: @UdayBabariya - yes, there is a typo in this answer. "guide.bottomAnchor" should be "guide.topAnchor". Give it a try - fixed it for me.

Comment: What would be the equivalent in Obj- c?

Answer (score 1):

The Obj-C version:

```
[[searchBackView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor constant:0] setActive:YES];
```

If you have **translucent bars** note: then the topLayoutGuide is below the bar,
e.g the statusBar.

see: [topLayoutGuide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621367-toplayoutguide?language=objc) It explains conditions which is important to consider.

Whereas the **safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor** would not be beneath the NavigationBars;
much simpler to work with.